# My htaccess file rewrite doesn't work

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, wildcard

my site address is : [http://Luxtext.life]
its a blog service.
I want to redirect for example amir.luxtext.life to luxtext.life/?s=amir
and this is my htaccess file codes :

```
RewriteEngine On


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.luxtext\.life [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\.luxtext\.life
RewriteRule (.*) user.php?s=%1&t=29&u=11&v=66 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.luxtext\.life [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\.luxtext\.life
RewriteRule (.*) user.php?s=%1&t=29&u=11&v=66 [L,QSA]


RewriteRule ^(.*)/post([a-zA-z0-9]+).php?$ /post.php?id=$1&p=$2
RewriteRule ^(.*)/post-([a-zA-z0-9]+).php?$ /post.php?id=$1&p=$2
RewriteRule ^(.*)/post_([a-zA-z0-9]+).php?$ /post.php?id=$1&p=$2

RewriteRule ^(.*)/page([^/]+).php?$ /page.php?id=$1&b=$2
RewriteRule ^(.*)/page-([^/]+).php?$ /page.php?id=$1&b=$2
RewriteRule ^(.*)/page_([^/]+).php?$ /page.php?id=$1&b=$2



RewriteRule ^([a-zA-z0-9]+)/post([a-zA-z0-9]+).php?$ /post.php?id=$1&p=$2
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-z0-9]+)/post-([a-zA-z0-9]+).php?$ /post.php?id=$1&p=$2
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-z0-9]+)/post_([a-zA-z0-9]+).php?$ /post.php?id=$1&p=$2

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-z0-9]+)/page([^/]+).php?$ /page.php?id=$1&b=$2
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-z0-9]+)/page-([^/]+).php?$ /page.php?id=$1&b=$2
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-z0-9]+)/page_([^/]+).php?$ /page.php?id=$1&b=$2
```

but it doesn't word.
my wildcard is on and mu host is Cpanel. thanks.

Comment: The rules look ok on superficial sight. Might it be that you have not enabled the interpretation of `.htaccess` style files at all? Try placing a definite syntax error in that file and make a request. Do you really get an error?

Comment: Why don't you define such rewriting rules in the real http host configuration instead of using `.htaccess` style files?

Comment: @arkascha can you explain more ?

Comment: look @arkascha .. for testing the htaccess i wrote a sample redirect and it worked.. but when i wrote this rewrite rules it shows me only a blank page and doesn't redirect correctly. for example you can check amir.luxtext.life and luxtext.life/user.php?s=amir&t=29&u=11&v=66

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't redirect correctly"? With a "blank page" I would expect no redirection to get applied? What does your http servers error log file say? And how does your comment answer my suggestions?

Comment: it's my error in my error_log : client denied by server configuration: /home/zix1/public_html/luxtext.life/.htaccess .. can you tell me the problem ? @arkascha

Comment: Well, this says that this file is not readable. A pretty clear issue. Keep in mind that in a multi user environment the http server process is executed under another user account than your personal one. So what you ahve to do is: 1. examine what file permissions that file actually has. 2. find out what user and group account the http server is executed under. 3. adjust the file permissions such that the http server process _can_ read that file.

Comment: @arkascha all of my permissions are 777 ... i think one of functions in my server is off ... can you guess whats that function ?

Comment: File permissions of `0777` is a bad idea in general, it raises huge security issues. But ok fine, for a test, let's first check for other causes. The error message you get however is crystal clear: the http server is not allowed to read that file. There has to be a reason. If not file permissions, then it has to be your http hosts configuration. I suggest you add the relevant sections to your question above (there is an `edit` link below it, _use it_).

Comment: @arkascha I have enough access to enable or disable a function in php. can you suggest me a function to turn on or off to solve the problem ?

Comment: The http server configuration cannot be altered by means of php. That makes sense: it would be an obvious security nightmare. The error message you posted in a comment above ("client denied by server configuration") says that the http server configuration prevents access to the file. I cannot tell you why that is, what details, since I have no access to your system, you have. Remember that I cannot look over your shoulder. That is why I asked you to post the relevant sections of your configuration. If you have no access to that then you have to get assistance from someone who does.